# External USB C Monitor not being recognised on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, asus, 17.04, usb-c

I have an ASUS-Zenbook UX310UA-GL160R and I am trying to connect a second monitor through usb-c to DVI adapter.

- Second screen is okay.  Tested it with another machine.
- Monitor not being detected when using **gnome-control-center display**
- lsusb and dmesg are not showing any signs of a device being plugged in.
- Ubuntu 17.04 up to date using Kernel **4.10.0-26-generic**
- This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 with no additional drivers installed.

lsusb **without** adapter:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58d2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb **with** adapter:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58d2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci -d ::0c03 -k

```
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Interesting excerpt from **dmesg**

```
[190917.168090] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[190917.247452] usb 1-2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[190918.187587] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[190918.267489] usb 1-2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[190919.367524] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[190919.447613] usb 1-2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[190919.799798] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[190919.879814] usb 1-2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[190920.067646] usb 1-2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32                                                                                                                                           
[190920.255782] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[190920.335681] usb 1-2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[190920.523584] usb 1-2.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32                                                                                                                                           
[190920.711533] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[190920.711610] usb 1-2.1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190920.919810] usb 1-2.1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190921.127608] usb 1-2.1: device not accepting address 15, error -71
[190921.211570] usb 1-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[190921.211719] usb 1-2.1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190921.419750] usb 1-2.1: Device not responding to setup address.
[190921.627627] usb 1-2.1: device not accepting address 16, error -71
[190921.627683] usb 1-2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device                                                                                                                                             
[219005.641806] TCP: wlp2s0: Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.
[225099.538252] perf: interrupt took too long (7692 > 7690), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 26000
[279884.408604] usb 1-2.3: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
```

My ASUS-Zenbook UX310UA-GL160R Specs:

https://www.asus.com/au/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX310UA/specifications/

[My USB-C to DVI Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKuSL.jpg)